# Reading XML in a string and write to text file in c#

Tags: asp.net, .net, xml, c#-4.0

I have XML content that I am retrieving from a service and I want to write it into a text file. I am getting this XML content in a string variable.

How can I read this and write in text file? Please help. I am getting data successfully using this code:

```
string results = "";
using (WebClient Web = new WebClient())
{
    results = Web.DownloadString(WebString.ToString());
}
```

I have tried some links, but they are not helping

- [forums.asp.net](http://forums.asp.net/t/1630414.aspx)
- [Reading-XML-File-and-Writing-it-to-txt-format-in-C](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/622601/Reading-XML-File-and-Writing-it-to-txt-format-in-C)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save it in a file, don't use `DownloadString` to start with - just use [`WebClient.DownloadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile.aspx).

If you *really* want to fetch it in memory and then save it, you can save it with:

```
File.WriteAllText(filename, results);
```

Note that this code doesn't depend on it being XML at all... nothing you're asking is XML-specific.

Comment: But In case of Web.DownloadString()  how to read it. just for knowledge.

Comment: no overload DownloadFile takes one argument error comes when I tried this

Comment: @Sandy: Well no, you need to specify the URL to fetch, and the file to save it to. Did you read the documentation? Which part was problematic? As for `DownloadString` - I don't know what you mean by "how to read it"... you've fetched it as a string...

Comment: yes I have fetched it as string  and it is present with me. now I want to write this string in text file.